# currentTime video always returning 0

Tags: javascript, html, video

I am making a custom player and I have the following problem:

When I try to to click in certain parts of the progress bar to advance the video, it doesn't work and it always returns the value of 0 in the currentTime property.

I am using the currentTime to try to advance the time of the video like that:

```
 $("#videoCurso").get(0).currentTime = 100;
```

but it always return to 0.

Can someone help with that?

Comment: have you loaded the video (and waited for metadata loading to complete), and is `$("#videoCurso").get(0)` the `<video>` element from the DOM?

Comment: Why use `.get()` on an id?

Comment: because jquery returns an array

Comment: Could you include an [MCVE]  ? Where does the video comes from (is it a stream or a file ?) Does it do it on every browsers or just one (if so which one) ?  What codecs is your video encoded with ?

Comment: It's a video/mp4 file and doesn't work at all

Comment: i just checked it out and in firefox its working fine, but in chrome is not working

Comment: "*What codec is your video encoded with ?*"

Comment: mp4 with h.264.

Comment: it's problem with django, thank you guys